# How to show values in my pandas_bokeh chart legend?

Tags: python, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

I have a very small pandas DataFrame with two columns.

```
    status          count
0   early           2
1   on_time         2
2   late            1
3   Incomplete      9
```

I am trying to create a pie chart using **pandas_bokeh** library, but I am having some trouble with the legend and I can't quite figure out why. Here is the code for the chart:

```
df2.plot_bokeh.pie(
    x="status",
    y="count",
    legend="top_right",
    title="Task completion times")
```

This gives me the following graph:

[image]

As you can see, the legend shows **__x__values**. How do I change this so that it shows the different **status** values from my dataframe??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this is actually a bug that I can reproduce using the standard example  [here](https://github.com/PatrikHlobil/Pandas-Bokeh#pieplot). I opened an issue: https://github.com/PatrikHlobil/Pandas-Bokeh/issues/78

Comment: Thanks Patrik. I couldn't understand why it wasn't working, but glad it's not just me.